# What is an NDArray in octave

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, types, octave

What is an *NDArray* in octave? What does the "ND" in *NDArray* stand for? Seemed like a case for Google, but I could not find any good descriptions.

Comment: I believe it stands for `N-Dimensional`. `N` being a number when you say it out aloud like `2-Dimensinal Array` etc

Comment: @Popeye: Can you write an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: @Andy I've added an answer though I was boarder line thinking it should be a comment over an answer as it's quite short but there isn't much else to say about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the `ND` in `NDArray` stands for `N-Dimensional`. `N` being a number when you say it out aloud like `2-Dimensional Array` etc.

Comment: Indeed kind of obvious when you say it :) The reason why I came up with the question in the first place was that I couldn't add a NDArray to a matrix, despite being of the same dimensions. However, the most annoying thing was that I couldn't figure out what ND stood for, so thanks for clearing that up. :)